# Unable to create a Rest end-point

Tags: rest-api

I'm tring to make an Ajax call in my plugin.
My front-end code tryes to call Rest my POST API wp-json/imp/search-cert

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function (\$scope,\$http ){
        \$scope.valore = 'pippo';
        \$scope.cerca = function(){
            \$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: './wp-json/imp/search-cert',
                data: \$scope.query
            }).then(function (response) {
                \$scope.valore = 'pluto';   
            }, function (error, status) {
                //\$scope.show_error_message('Errore', error.data.message);
            });   

        }
    });

</script>
```

I registered the API with this code

```
function read_certificate_func( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'certId' => $data['certId'],
    ) );

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $posts[0]->post_title;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'imp',
        '/search-cert',
        array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
        'callback' => 'read_certificate_func',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    ) );
} );
```

but when I invoke the API wordpress replays with 404 error
I've tried to put a break-point inside read_certificate_func but the function in not processed at all.

Comment: Are you sure the request is going to the correct URL? I don't use Angular, but are you sure this URL format is supported: `'./wp-json/imp/search-cert'`, specifically the `./`?

Comment: My browser calls http://localhost/icdq/wp-json/imp/search-cert  the root of my site is http://localhost/icdq

Comment: @RobertoPetrilli, "but the function in not processed at all" - then are you sure your route and endpoint are being registered correctly? You can confirm that by visiting localhost/icdq/wp-json/imp/ and/or localhost/icdq/?rest_route=/imp - if that page is giving you a 404 error or that `search-cert` isn't anywhere on the page, then your route or endpoint is not being registered.

Comment: Also - a note: the route namespace, i.e. 1st parameter for `register_rest_route()`, should be in the form of `<vendor or plugin>/<version>`, so you should use something like `imp/v1` and not just `imp`.

Comment: @Sally changes  the registration this way   register_rest_route( 'cerca-certificati/v1', '/search-cert',  ...  and it worked! The end point localhost/icdq/?rest_route=/cerca-certificati/v1/search-cert is now avaliable, but wp-json/cerca-certificati/v1/search-cert is not. May I have issues in production where the url is different? Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it

Comment: Actually, even with just `imp`, your code worked fine for me, so I don't think the problem was with the missing version string, and my previous comment was just so that you know the proper namespace format. So maybe it's just a caching issue or that you forgot to load the file which registers the endpoint. As for the pretty endpoint URL (`/wp-json/<route>`), if you have URL rewriting enabled, then you can try flushing the rewrite rules by simply visiting the Permalinks Settings admin page, and just check if `/wp-json/cerca-certificati/v1/search-cert` now works.

Answer (score 0):

As of WordPress 5.5, `register_rest_route()`'s `permission_callback` argument is required. You should be receiving/logging an error message to the effect of

```
PHP Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. The REST API route definition
for /search-cert is missing the required permission_callback argument. For REST API
routes that are intended to be public, use __return_true as the permission callback.
```

More on the `permission_callback` argument can be found [in the REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#permissions-callback).

Comment: I added 'permission_callback' => '__return_true' but wordpress keeps responding 404, I also update my question